# Will I pay customs fees when ordering a “sold by Amazon EU” good on Amazon UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit, customs

I would like to buy a ca. £75 item on `amazon.co.uk` which is “Sold by: Amazon EU”, and to be delivered in the UK (England).

The confirmation pane looks like this (promotion = free delivery):

[image]

**Question:** Should I then expect to pay customs fees when receiving the parcel?

I still struggle with the subtleties of the UK-EU free trade agreement, and [there have been stories](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-55734277) about hefty duties (+ processing fees) to be paid upon receiving an order.

Comment: Related: [Implications of brexit for UK-EU personal purchases and sales](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/135247/39012)

Comment: Most likely you will have to pay import tax, unless the seller is breaking the law.

Comment: Where are you located/do you want the goods to be delivered? I assumed you were in the UK but reading your answer, I am not sure anymore.

Comment: @Relaxed you are right: I've detailed that the good it to be delivered in the UK (specifically Britain, and not NI).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is more an empirical observation than a justified answer, but **“something” happens around the £150 threshold:** When the total of goods “sold by Amazon EU” exceeds it, a deposit for “import fees” is added to the order (as seen in the confirmation page):

[image]

---

Edit: According to The Guardian in [*Customers in Europe hit by post-Brexit charges when buying from UK*](https://web.archive.org/web/20210202144402/https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2021/jan/07/customers-europe-hit-by-post-brexit-charges-buying-from-uk), **the threshold is actually 150€**:

> Despite the tariff-free deal, customs duties will apply to goods ordered from the UK that do not originate from Britain. Goods ordered from and manufactured in the UK should not attract customs duty, but **products ordered from the UK worth more than that €150 and shipped from outside Britain** will.

---

P.-S.: I eventually ordered the (≤ 150€) good, received it, and *I didn't had to pay anything extra* upon collection.

Comment: Where are you located? €150 is the regular threshold for customs duties for private imports from a business from a third-country *to* the EU.

Comment: Note that you might be hit with a VAT bill (the tax itself + handling fees from the shipping company) for much lower amounts (this has happened to be for things shipped from the US to the Netherlands for example). The screenshot suggests Amazon takes care of this though so that might not be an issue in this case.

Comment: I want the goods to be delivered in England. Indeed, I understand Amazon might have already factored the “subtract EU VAT but add UK VAT back” part of the transaction. (That's what I'm hoping for at least!)